# Excel 2003 How to feed two sheets into pivot table?

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2003, vba

If I had two sheets with same column structure - is there a way to use them as data source for a pivot table **within the same workbook**?

Something like: `select * from sheet1 union all select * from sheet2` ?

Comment: my apologies - misunderstood question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I don't know if this is appropriate but I am resubmitting a new answer**

You can do what you want and create a data query in MSQuery from Excel.
Save the query as a datasource and then use that datasource for your pivot table.
The caveat is trying to consolidate sheets in the same workbook you are wanting to pivot. MSQUERY tries to open the file as a datasource which is already open by you.
This may not be exactly what you hope to achieve, but may get you closer.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here you should just save the query as a datasource

[image]

Comment: the range consolidation doesnt give you all the columns in the pivot. If you would finish the wizard you will see that instead of columns you would expect from the sheets you get Row and Column something like that.... completely different.. try and see for yourself

Comment: people who vote this answer up. can you explain why are you so excited? really

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will remove my response, because this does not work at all as it appears it should. Unless someone else has an explanation for why. I wonder if an OLAP cube would achieve what you want as a datasource. I will investigate further.

Comment: @Bobb I edited and provided a different possible solution for your pivot table and am not sure if you have to have everything in a single workbook or not, but you can do a Union query

Comment: this is not the answer I was looking for but it seems there is no answer really so i marked yours...... the problem is - user wants everything in same workbook......